# Rebinding <"Return> Key to a new function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The program has an entry and a button that submits the info in it.
First it takes an int value to know how many times are you going to input information and after gathering up all the inputs after that, it shows you one of them ramdonly.
I binded the <"Return"> key so you don't have to click the button manually but do to the fact that two different functions are in play, i'm having a problem rebinding the key to work with the second function. How could i solve it?

```
window.title("Decidir que mierda ver con Mora")
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(background="light blue")

x = None
item = ""
list = []

#cantidad de items (el event activa el Enter)
def cantidad_items(event):
    x= int(texto1.get())
    texto1.delete(0, END)
    texto1.bind("<Return>",añadir)
    boton1.configure(text = "Ingresar", command= lambda:añadir(x))
    
#nombre de los items   
def añadir(x):
    item = texto1.get()
    list.append(item)
    texto1.delete(0, END)
    if len(list)== x:
        texto1.destroy()
        boton1.destroy()
        rando = random.choice(list)
        resultado = Label(window, text=rando, font= "Helvetica 30")
        resultado.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor= CENTER)
        
#primer entry del número
texto1 = Entry(window, font = "Helvetica 20", width = 22)
texto1.bind("<Return>", cantidad_items)
texto1.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)


#botón ejecución del input
boton1 = Button(window, text = "Ingresar", command = cantidad_items)
boton1.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, anchor= CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. If you want to run two functions with one `Return` at the same time then bind to Return function which execute both functions.

Comment: BTW: in `cantidad_items` you have to use `global x` to assign value to external variable `x` - without `global` it creates local variable `x`.

Comment: when I use `print()` in both function then I see it rebinds `<Return>`. It seems it works. But your real problem can be that you use local `x` in `cantidad_items()`  and binded function `añadir(x)` gets `event` as first value so you get `x = event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `print()` in both functions then you will see it rebinds `<Return>`.

Your real problem is different.

In `cantidad_items()` you have to use `global x` to inform function to assign `x = ...` to external/global variable. Without `global` it create local variable `x`

Bind executes `añadir(x)` with argument `event` and it creates local variable `x` and assigns `event` to `x`. At the same time in `command=` you runs it with global `x` and it assigns gloabal `x` to local `x`. You could create `añadir(event=None)` to run it in bind with `event` and in `command=añadir` without any value - and then when you try to get value from `x` then it will get from global `x`

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#cantidad de items (el event activa el Enter)
def cantidad_items(event):
    global x

    print('cantidad_items')
    
    x = int(texto1.get())
    texto1.delete(0, END)

    texto1.bind("<Return>", añadir)
    boton1.configure(text="Ingresar", command=añadir)
    
#nombre de los items   
def añadir(event=None): # bind() runs with argument, command= runs without argument

    print('añadirb')

    item = texto1.get()
    data.append(item)
    texto1.delete(0, END)

    if len(data) == x:
        texto1.destroy()
        boton1.destroy()
        rando = random.choice(data)
        resultado = Label(window, text=rando, font="Helvetica 30")
        resultado.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

# --- main ---

x = 0
data = []  # don't use name `list` 

window = Tk()

window.title("Decidir que mierda ver con Mora")
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(background="light blue")

#primer entry del número
texto1 = Entry(window, font="Helvetica 20", width=22)
texto1.bind("<Return>", cantidad_items)
texto1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)

#botón ejecución del input
boton1 = Button(window, text="Ingresar", command=cantidad_items)
boton1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```